# Inductor Based on capacitor and gyrator

Tags: capacitor, inductor, gyrator

I was trying to implement Inductor using capacitor in Lt spice. But the circuit waveform is not steady.
[image]

[image]
Also the impedance is not exactly proportional to frequency. please explain this deviation.

Comment: I'm confused.  Are you trying to make a "simulated inductor"? https://wiki.analog.com/university/courses/electronics/text/chapter-4#simulated_inductor

Comment: Please, give us a some more information about the used principle. For example: I cannot identify a typical GIC-block which normally is used to realize an electronic inductor. What is the purpose of the whole circuit? Filtering?

Comment: He's implementing gyrator using opamps, a similar question is here also <https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/532427/preventing-opamp-from-possible-saturation-maybe?noredirect=1#comment1374621_532427>