# Preventing opamp from possible saturation maybe

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, ltspice, saturation, gyrator

I am trying to simulate a gyrator circuit for implementing capacitor as inductor in LTSpice. While simulation I am encountering the following problem :
[image] It seems that top left opamp undergoes saturation, as it gives clipped output blue one is the output green one is the input, like this below : [image]

Please some one look and explain what's the problem, if I remove the top left opamp, I get sinusoidal waveforms.
I think this maybe due to saturation, but how to prevent it?
Some one explain.

UPDATE: when I tried with 1uF capacitance instead of 0.01uF, it works fine.(why?)

Comment: R4 and R6 are unreasonably small and require immense current from the opamp output. U2 is also effectively shorted out and can be removed from the circuit without changing anything. It's output can never do anything.

Comment: R4 and R6 have different value as I was experimenting, Even if they have 2k and 1k values error is still there?

Comment: @DKNguyen can you explain why you said U2 is shorted out? U2 was used to adjust the current, so that gyrator works. Its output is providing current across 10k resistor.

Comment: @beta_meme_beta Did you intend for `U2` to have a positive feedback? Also, a gyrator is usually made with current sources, so you may need Norton amplifiers, though since I can't see what opamps you have, I can't be sure.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I have used Universal opamp 2, and have used amplifiers to get the following relation V2/I1 =(-)V1/I2, I am actually using amplifiers to generate current across 10k by producing suitable potential drops across each 10k resistor next to amplifiers.

Comment: UPDATE: when I use 1uF instead of 0.01uF it works fine

Comment: Can you figure out how to insert an image properly or is there a problem with imgur today? (It happens.)

Comment: I'm so confused.  This question just got posted too and it's nearly identical.  Are you the same person?  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/532364/inductor-based-on-capacitor-and-gyrator

Comment: He's from my college

Comment: @Transistor tried fixing it.

Comment: @beta_meme_beta: Success.